# Typescript - declare a generic method

Tags: typescript

I am creating a configuration class, and I would like to add a property to assign any type of functions, with any return type and any number of parameters.

How can I declare this ?

I tried this:

```
export class ParamClass {
    param1: string;
    param2: string;
    onclick: (...args: any[]) => {};
}
```

This is working but the return type of the assigned method cannot be void.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `any` or `unknown` as the return type. Such a signature would accept `void`:

```
export class ParamClass {
    param1: string;
    param2: string;
    onclick: (...args: any[]) => unknown;
}

new ParamClass().onclick = () => { }
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=7&ssc=37&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4AUVRQWwGFUM4BvAKDmrjFwIEYAuONGKASwDsBzAbio06efACYWbTrwE04ELsg4IA1iwAUAOi24eaFii4BPANoBdAJRwAvAD44AVy7KuEAO5cBAXwoUuwV9j0RCRoauYa8ooq1nBh1nZkcJ5AA)